# How to redirect a url with .php to 404

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm working on a php project and I have successfully removed .php extension from the URL using .htaccess. But I can easily access the url by typing .php too. Is there any way to redirect to 404 when there is .php in url

This is how my .htaccess looks like -

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html
```

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..but you are redirecting to *.php and if you add another redirection from *.php to 404 page you may end up redirecting all your pages ( without php -> with php -> 404) to 404 page.

Common practice is to redirect all "SEO" urls (those without .php extension) to a single php file (i.e. index.php). Then you can redirect all other .php files to 404 page with exception of that index.php.

This solution is good because in index.php you can do some common stuff, needed for all pages (i.e. connect to database, check authentication or something) and then from index.php include appropriate file to generate page content.

Change to your file .htaccss should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1
```

and then your index.php will get page name inside get `$page` parameter so you can include appropriate file..

--

For excluding index.php from redirection you should add extra rewrite condition, which should look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
```

.. meaning, request uri must not be index.php for this redirection to work. Place this with other conditiones, above redirect rule of course.
You have online htaccess tester tools. Try it for your self.

Comment: So what I should do is create parameters in index.php like 'index.php?page=about' and get it through GET and call that about page accordingly?

Comment: You have to add extra condition to avoid redirecting index.phi it self.

Comment: How can I do that, I have no idea?

Comment: Upated my answer.